# Use a light panel with Elementary (or other GTK+ themes that use dark panels)?

Tags: gnome-panel, themes, elementary-theme

When using Elementary (at least, using the Controls), it makes the panel dark, and I'd like to use a light panel. How can I change this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and use this command:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
   ```

   [image]
2. Scroll to the bottom of the file and find the line `include "Apps/panel-dark.rc`

   [image]
3. Replace `panel-dark.rc` with `panel.rc`

   [image]
4. Save the file, and then switch to a different theme and then switch back to Elementary.

   [image]